# Every single Drop Down List throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" no matter what page they are on

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Every drop down list that has the property "autopostback" set to true throws the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" during run time. No errors are thrown in debugging. It doesn't seem to matter what page they are on or even if they are bound to a data source. Nothing in my configuration was changed that I know of since they started doing this.

The .net error is as follows:

```
    Server Error in '/Nominations' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu.Internal.MenuHorizontalSpacingControl.PrepareSpacingControl(WebControl control, MenuItem item, Boolean isSeparatorSpacing) +119
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu.Internal.MenuHorizontalSpacingControl.PrepareControlHierarchy() +80
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTableCell.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +47
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTableRow.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +58
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +206
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +81
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer) +73
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +57
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTableCell.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +58
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTableRow.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +58
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +206
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +81
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer) +73
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer) +73
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer) +73
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer) +205
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +163
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4206; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4209
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something about that DevExpress menu control, which I am guessing is on a master page, which is why it is happening on every page. As for why, I don't think it's related to the drop down control, only with the fact that it's posting back.

You'll want to look into where that control is getting it's data from to see if that's null or perhaps contact DevExpress to see if it's an issue with the control.

Comment: Wow... Its been a long day... Thanks. I am not sure how I missed that. It was your typical out of bounds error in the class I was using to manipulate the menu after binding.